# AWS Lambda: Unable to send file to FTP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ftp, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that generates a text file on S3 bucket. It is able to do so. Now, the problem I am facing is in the part where the same file is sent to FTP server. The FTP server is on the same VPC and I am using 'promise-ftp' module to send file to FTP. When this app runs on its own(without lambda function) it sends the file but as soon as I use the code as lambda function, FTP upload fails. Here is the code to upload file on FTP server:

```
function CreatefileOnFTP(fileData, fileName, event, context, callback) {
    console.log('Sending file to FTP...');
    var buf = Buffer.from(fileData, 'utf-8');
    var ftp = new PromiseFtp();
    ftp.connect(config.ftpDetails)
        .then(function (serverMessage) {
            ftp.put(buf, fileName);
            console.log('File sent successfully to FTP...');
        }).then(function () {
            ftp.end();
            callback(null, 'File sent successfully to FTP...');
        });
}
```

Since this is working code, I do believe there has to be something with the configuration in AWS console. Is anyone aware of the settings(creating endpooint for VPC to access FTP server etc.) to achieve the task? Moreover, is this(FTP upload) even possible from lambda function? Here is the cloudwatch log:

```
2019-04-23T07:05:53.984Z    03211d8d-e3f0-4c75-a938-386924601388 Unhandled rejection Error: Timeout while connecting to server at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/@icetee/ftp/lib/connection.js:329:24) at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11) at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5) at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the exact exception is: 2019-04-23T07:05:53.984Z 03211d8d-e3f0-4c75-a938-386924601388 Unhandled rejection Error: Timeout while connecting to server
at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/@icetee/ftp/lib/connection.js:329:24)
at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl even if I increase the timeout to 5 minutes, it gives the same error. It is a very small text file(in few KBs).

Comment: It seems to be linked to your security groups, can you check the inbound rules of the security group associated with your FTP server and the outbound rules of the security group associated with your Lambda function?